# App Engine - list of deployed files

Tags: google-app-engine

When using `appcfg.py update`, is there a way to get a list of files that were actually deployed?

I need this for making sure my `app.yaml` is correct and no unneeded files are deployed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's no such built-in functionality, but I think that you can get what you want by one of:

- Modify appcfg.py to print the files it is trying to upload. Look at `DoUpload` method which has `paths` argument.

  > An iterator that yields the relative paths of the files to upload.
- Or, probably easier way is to [download](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp?hl=en#Python_Downloading_source_code) your application source code from app engine:
  `appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>`